# File descriptor down after a fork with select

Tags: c, sockets, select, fork, file-descriptor

I have a problem in my code. I have a client and a server.
My server uses select to monitor the files descriptors of client socket and server socket.
After having started the client, the server monitors the client's socket without problem.
But, when i fork in my client to create another one and connects it with the server, the parent client file descriptor will never be called with the select server, after that.

Any suggestion ?

Thanks you.

Comment: What do you mean?  So you have a server that has a listening socket, and your client connects to this listening socket.  Then you fork in the client, and then the child process of the client creates another connection to this socket?

Comment: Yes, and after that, i dont understand for what reason, my server doesn't communicates with my parent client.

Comment: Are you accepting the connection and then passing this new file descriptor to your child process?  You can talk through one socket if you want to, its just a pain in the ass to have to distinguish both clients from one another (you have to put it in your transmission messages this way).  Using accept, you create a new socket for each client that connects, and then you select on: 1. Your parent client socket, 2: your child client socket.  If any client writes to the socket, select will find it.  I can bet that both client threads are writing to the same socket.

Comment: Also, its generally proven to be better to fork in your server as well, so that the parent server thread listens for connections and then disptaches a thread to handle the new file descriptor (created with accept).  Put the new FD in a ring buffer or something.  If you don't, I can't really see how your server thread can continue accepting connections if its busy responding to one of the clients.

Comment: That'll do it! Good luck.  Use Pthreads in your server and a ring buffer for accepted connections.  Thats how to make a fast server!